# C++: delete on pointers to structs

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the following code:

```
struct A {
    int someInt;
};

A *a = new A;
A *b;

delete a; // ok
delete b; // crash
```

It crashes, but I don't know why. I thought deleting null pointers is a no-op.

Do I even need to delete structs? Is it bad practice to create structs on the heap? Is it better to create them on the stack?

Comment: Is all of this code inside a function or just some of it? It makes a difference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleting null pointers *is* a no-op, yes, so if `b` were a null pointer then you'd be fine.

But it's not. It's an *uninitialised variable* with an *indeterminate value*.

Here's a null pointer:

```
A* b = nullptr;
```

*(If you write `A* b;` at global scope, or if you write `static A* b;` in a function, or if you are defining a static class member, then `b` has static storage duration and is automatically zero-initialised for you; this is the one exception to the rule.)*

And, yes, you should avoid dynamic allocation where possible — using it for no good reason complicates your code for, well, for no good reason.

Comment: So I need to explicitly say `A *b = NULL;`?

Answer (score 2):

`b` is a uninitialized pointer. There is nothing to delete.